# Keep Flask Running Without Web Page in Browser

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server

I have a local flask server that handles sensordata. It gets Temperaturevalues and adjusts a light when the temperature is greater than a certain threshold. So far it only works when one client keeps the browser with that page open. It would be nice if the server would update the temperature values and adjust the light without having the browser open all the time. How do I make it run in the background?

```
temperture = 0
threshold_temp = 0

def read_temp():
    #read temperature values

server = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(server)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server = server, url_base_pathname="/dash/")

@server.route('/_stuff')
def stuff():
    global threshold_temp
    temperature = read_temp()
    if temperature >= threshold_temp:
            #change light
    else:
            #do not change light
    return jsonify(result = temperature)

#Change Threshold
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    global threshold_temp
    threshold_temp = float(msg)
    send(msg, broadcast=True)
    f = open("Threshold.txt", "w")
    f.write(msg)
    f.close()

#Adjust Threshold on Connection of Client
@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    global threshold_temp
    f = open("Threshold.txt", "r")
    threshold_temp = float(f.read())
    send(threshold_temp, broadcast=True)

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(server, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
```

Comment: You can use scheduler and schedule it to run every second. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427781/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-flask-function-every-specific-interval-of-time-and)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run a background task; message brokers are a good way to handle that kind of thing. [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) and [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) are good options for this.